# Which one is use $.ajax() or $http.get() in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an angularjs project and want to write common class for calling APIs in async and sync. The code looks like:

```
var cas = cas || {}; 
cas.processor = (function () {   
    var async = function (url, data, action, callback) {   
        $.ajax({
            url: global.baseURL + url,
            type: action,
            data: data,                
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }; 
    return {
        async: async
    };
});
```

but in angularjs use like

```
ar app = angular.module('appUsers', []);
app.controller('userController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:56110/APIs/Setting/Get').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $scope.users = data;
        })
});
```

Which methodology is best in an angularjs project? I want to write a common class like $.ajax() in angularjs.

Comment: Second option seems shorter. If performance is the same, I'd take the second

Comment: When in AngularJS, you should write Angularjs code. There's no reason to force it into a jQuery-like syntax.

Comment: but I want to write the common class for each APIs call(Just like ajax call). Is it possible in angularjs?

Comment: The second option is the recommended method for AngularJS. Most jQuery methods can be abstracted out if the AngularJS code base is properly formatted.

Comment: Ok, I understand! I am going to move second option and write the code for each APIs call. Thank you very much for the suggestion!!

Comment: angular is designed to avoid using JQuery to mitigate the DOM operation as it provides directive. but angular still encapsulates JQuery as JQLite as a subset of JQuery. so you should use angular service as much as possible

Comment: Neither of the approaches above makes use of promises. I strongly recommend you look into how to use promises. They are the future of JavaScript.

Comment: @JLRishe `$http.get()` return a promise.

Comment: @marquez Sorry, I was unclear. `$http.get()` returns a promise and `$.ajax()` returs a "sort of" promise, but neither of OP's code examples is making use of those promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project is in angualrjs then do not use jquery's ajax function.
Because after response of ajax function of jquery it calls success callback and update result. But angular does not know about this call, beacause it is out of its scope. Therefore even though data is updated angular does not update view part.

Therefore you should use angulars ajax function.

I hope this is useful for you.